# filter geom data by polygons and generate new column with specific values

Tags: r, filter, polygon

I have a data frame "roof" with roof areas in the format geom. In this dataframe there are other columns with information like ID, solar yield etc..

Beside the data set "roof" I have two polygons "transformercircleA" and "transformercircleB", which were imported with st_read(".kml").

Now I want to filter the data from the data frame "roof" for the polygon "transformercircleA" and add a new column "transformercircle" in the data frame "roof" and store the value "A". Then I want to do the same for the polygon "transformercircleB". That means I take the data frame "roof", filter for polygon "transformercircleB" and write the value "B" into the new column "transformercircle" generated before.

I think this would be possible with a for loop. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Is `transformercircleA` really a polygon or just a point with a given diameter? Which Geodetic CRS are you using? Please specify the geometry type [(see here)](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html) and provide some example data (text and not image). Then you can use functions `st_overlap` and `st_within` of the sf package.

Comment: @danlooo this is transformercircleA. 
imple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 9.385368 ymin: 47.4587 xmax: 9.390964 ymax: 47.46212
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  Name Description                       geometry
1                  POLYGON ((9.38765 47.4621, ...